# Locust unit of measurement

Tags: locust

Anyone know what the time unit of measurement is on locust? I can't find this on their website. My guess is ms, but would like confirmation.

http://locust.io/

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's in millisecond since the min_wait and max_wait are based on that.

Comment: From `API docs`: `TaskSet class

class TaskSet(parent)
Class defining a set of tasks that a Locust user will execute.

When a TaskSet starts running, it will pick a task from the tasks attribute, execute it, call it’s wait function which will sleep a random number between min_wait and max_wait milliseconds. It will then schedule another task for execution and so on.`